# Swift - Perform Segue from map annotation

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, segue, mkannotation

I have 1 pin on my map. I need to pass title of annotation to another UIView (which is ikinciEkran.swift in that case). But I am unable to do so.

Here is the segue part of my code and I do not know how to segue title of selected annotation.

I only pasted related part of the code.

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, CLLocationManagerDelegate, MKMapViewDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_Name: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_Address: UILabel!
@IBOutlet weak var lbl_Phone: UILabel!

var LocationManager = CLLocationManager()

var i = 0

var annotation:MKAnnotation!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    LocationManager.delegate = self
    mapView.delegate = self

    LocationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
    LocationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    LocationManager.startUpdatingLocation()

    let tekel1 = TekelClass(
        title: "tekel1",
        locationName: "Tekelİsim1",
        coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 40.9400, longitude: 29.300520))

    mapView.addAnnotation(tekel1)

}

 func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView!,
    calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl!) {
        if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
            performSegueWithIdentifier("toTheMoon", sender: self)

        }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toTheMoon" )
    {
        var ikinciEkran = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        ikinciEkran.tekelName = "how to segue title of the selected pin"

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to implement `viewForAnnotation` method.

example.

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, viewForAnnotation annotation: MKAnnotation!) -> MKAnnotationView! {

    if annotation is MKUserLocation {
        return nil
    }

    let reuseId = "pin"

    var pinView = mapView.dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(reuseId)
    if pinView == nil {
        pinView = MKPinAnnotationView(annotation: annotation, reuseIdentifier: reuseId)
        pinView?.canShowCallout = true

        var rightButton: AnyObject! = UIButton.buttonWithType(UIButtonType.DetailDisclosure)
        rightButton.titleForState(UIControlState.Normal)

        pinView!.rightCalloutAccessoryView = rightButton as! UIView
    }
    else {
        pinView?.annotation = annotation
    }

    return pinView
}
```

If user tap (i) button on the annotation, `calloutAccessoryControlTapped` will be called.

[image]

ref. My MKMapView sample code
https://github.com/koogawa/MKMapViewSample

**EDIT**

```
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView, annotationView view: MKAnnotationView, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    if control == view.rightCalloutAccessoryView {
        performSegueWithIdentifier("toTheMoon", sender: view)
    }
}

override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "toTheMoon" )
    {
        var ikinciEkran = segue.destinationViewController as! DetailViewController

        ikinciEkran.tekelName = (sender as! MKAnnotationView).annotation!.title

    }

}
```

Comment: Dear Kosuke, how to segue title of the pin ? On your github example nothing passed-segued.