# Filter map annotations in Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, segue, mapbox

I have a MapView Controller that contains annotations along with other data, such as details and image information. I'm trying to filter the annotation and its associated data and then pass the data to a DetailView Controller when I click the detailDisclosure button in the callout accessory control.

I can only pass information separately. I can pass the annotation title and I can pass data for all annotations to the DetailView Controller. But my goal is to select the annotation, click the detailDisclosure button, pass information for the selected annotation, and view the title, subtitle, details and imageName in the DetailView Controller.

Any insights would be greatly appreciated.

Below is the code that I've been working on:

```
class LocationAnnotation: NSObject, MGLAnnotation {

var customPointAnnotation = CustomPointAnnotation()
var location: Location?
var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
var title: String?
var subtitle: String?
var imageObj = ""
var details: String?

init(coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, title: String, subtitle: String, imageObj: String, details: String, location: Location? = nil) {
    self.coordinate = coordinate
    self.title = title
    self.subtitle = subtitle
    self.imageObj = imageObj
    self.details = details
}
}
```

---

```
class MapViewController: UIViewController, MGLMapViewDelegate {

    var locs = [Location]()
}

func populateMap() {

    // Declare the CustomPointAnnotation and set its coordinates, title, subtitle, image.
    let point = CustomPointAnnotation()
    for loc in locs {
        point.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: loc.latitude, longitude: loc.longitude)
        point.title = loc.name
        point.subtitle = loc.category
        point.imageObj = loc.imageName

        // Add marker to the map.
        mapview.addAnnotation(point)

    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetail", sender: annotation.title!)

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {

        let controller = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
        controller.location = locs
        controller.data = sender as? String

    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

I was able to finally pass the data for each selected location by calling the CustomPointAnnotation. The following helped:

[Swift - Perform Segue from map annotation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33053832/swift-perform-segue-from-map-annotation)

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MGLMapView, annotation view: MGLAnnotation, calloutAccessoryControlTapped control: UIControl) {

  performSegue(withIdentifier: "moreDetail", sender: view) 

}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if (segue.identifier == "moreDetail") {

        let controller = segue.destination as! DetailsViewController
        controller.titleShow = (sender as! CustomPointAnnotation).title
        controller.subtitle = (sender as! CustomPointAnnotation).subtitle
        controller.imageName = (sender as! CustomPointAnnotation).imageObj
        controller.details = (sender as! CustomPointAnnotation).details

    }
}
```

Comment: In `prepare(for segue:sender:)`, do something like `controller.location = myMapView.selectedAnnotations.first`

Comment: How do you set the data into the mapView ? Where is the code linking the dictionary with the location ?

Comment: I updated my question with a solution. Thanks for your suggestions.